# No module named 'clean-text' after installing it with Conda

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to use the clean-text package.

For installation I used `conda install -n nlp -c conda-forge clean-text`, where nlp is my virtual environment name. When I run `from cleantext import clean` using nlp environment, I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\SZXFL9~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16796/1988090573.py in <module>
----> 1 from cleantext import clean

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cleantext'
```

Other imports like pandas etc. work using this virtual environment, but I installed them via the conda GUI. However, also clean-text is displayed in the GUI, so it must be installed.

How can that problem be solved?

Comment: can you do "conda list" in your terminal to see if cleantext is installed? It looks like you may not be executing the program in the right environment.

Comment: When I do "conda list", cleantext is not in the list. So maybe my install command was not correct? I definetly use the right environment, since I selected it in Visual Studio Code and checked it multiple times. Btw what does "conda list" show? For which environment do I get the list?

Comment: I think you just haven't activated the environment. do "conda activate nlp", you should see (nlp) at the beginning of your terminal prompt . Then retry "conda list".

Comment: Ah okay. When I activate the environment, I get clean-text in the list created by "conda list"

Comment: then if you execute your program from this terminal, it should work fine

Comment: Could it maybe be somethin with the name? The package is called clean-text (with a hyphen) and when I import it, I write it without the hyphen (as the package documentation says)

Comment: I don't know how to run a jupyter notebook in a terminal, since I always ran it in Visual Studio Code. But since I have selected nlp as an interpreter there, it should also work there too. I did not experience such problem with other packages yet.

Comment: It is normal, the name shown in the "conda list" can be slightly different from the import name. Follow documentation is good. But did you try executing your program with the right environment? Are you executing your program in the terminal "python your_program.py" or via a play button on an IDE. If it is the latter, then ensure the right environment is selected in the IDE too

Comment: I use the play button in Visual Studio Code. I selected the nlp environment und the interpreter selection window says, that the current interpreter is '~\.conda\envs\nlp\python.exe', so I am quite sure, that the right one is selected

Comment: OK so there are a cleantext and a clean-text packages.  you may have both. can you do "pip freeze" in a terminal with your conda environment? If you have a package called cleantext, just uninstall with "pip uninstall cleantext"

Comment: Holy shit. You were right, I was using the wrong environment. Whatever I change in the interpreter settings does not affect anything. There is another setting in the document window called "Kernel" and this is where I have to change something. Now it works.

Comment: OK great, glad it works